# NetworkX: Betweenness Centrality does not take weights into account

Tags: python, networkx

Even though there have been questions on this before, I still decided to open a new question since the issue seemingly has not been resolved by NetworkX yet.

Regardless of which attribute I use as weight in `nx.betweenness_centrality(G, weight="attribute_name")`, I get the same output.

Does anyone know, how to fix this issue?

Does anyone know, how I could code the betweenness algorithm myself?

Comment: Do you have some example data / code you could show re: what you've tried so far? [The implementation in networkX](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.betweenness_centrality.html) seems to support weights so the first thing that comes to mind is to check if you're attributes are numerical? The other thing to note would be that weights in the implementation are always interpreted as distances, so if you have similarity weights you would need to invert those for your use case. You could also try the `load_centrality` function.

Comment: You could also try to repeat with the [iGraph implementation](https://igraph.org/python/api/latest/igraph._igraph.GraphBase.html#betweenness) and see if the results are any different? iGraph has a [utility function to convert your graph from networkX directly](https://igraph.org/python/api/latest/igraph.Graph.html#from_networkx) so should be a trivial thing to try out!